# font-family not working for true-type fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome, truetype

In my CSS file I first include my **true type** font file like this:

```
@font-face {font-family: "ss5"; src: url(../fonts/sans_serif/paneuropa-b.ttf);}
```

And then use it like this:

```
font-family: ss5;
```

But for some reason this only works in Linux and on Chrome, while it doesn't work on Windows Chrome... Weird, because my **.ttf** file is located on my server. Any Idea why this is so? I need this to work on all browsers.

Here is [my webpage](http://ziga-lausegger.com/strani/index.php) if anyone would like to check it out.

Comment: In my browser (Chrome on Windows 7) your web page produces a code 404 (Not Found) on the font file http://ziga-lausegger.com/fonts/sans_serif/paneuropa-b.ttf. My guess is you have the font installed locally on Linux, but not on your Windows box, and the file really *isn't* reachable through the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receive a `404` error when I request the font:

`http://ziga-lausegger.com/fonts/sans_serif/paneuropa-b.ttf`

I've tried to access the folder path in Chrome, and it worked. **You should block directory listing in your server configuration.** You can check that `paneuropa-b.ttf` doesn't exist in directory listing.

http://ziga-lausegger.com/fonts/sans_serif/

And like @aldo said, "guess is you have the font installed locally on Linux", because of this only worked on Linux.

Comment: Wowwwww I lost a file somehow... Don't even know when that happened. I ll upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid way to use font face. You have to generate font using `ttf`, `woff`,`eot`,`svg` to get all browser and OS. Where you used only `ttf`.  Generate your font then use.

You can use these sites below to generate font as ttf,woff,eot and svg.

1. http://www.fontsquirrel.com
2. http://www.font2web.com/ etc

Comment: For every font i have **ttf** and **svg** files. Sure this isn't enough?

Comment: yea, not enough for old browsers. some time in light devices, like mobile.

Comment: This is very bad cargo-cult advice. In practical terms nowadays opentype is sufficient almost everywhere. The few browsers that can not process it have other problems. They will look bad with the fonts or without them. So definitely not worth the complexity of multi-format (that need testing, that web designers mess up, etc). Besides SVG fonts for example lack hinting so they won't render well. Use opentype and enable transparent compression (gzip/deflate) in the web server and you're done. http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf